# copying part of the char array to a string in c

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, arrays

I have read many suggested questions, but still cannot find out the answer. I know the content in buffer is a NULL terminated `char array`, and I want to copy it into a dynamic allocated `char array`. However, I kept getting segmentation fault from the `strcpy` function. Thanks for any help.

```
void myFunction()
{
    char buffer[200];

    // buffer was filled by recvfrom correctly, and can be printed out with printf()
    char *message = malloc(200);

    strcpy(message, buffer[1]);
}
```

////////////////

ok, so i tried `strcpy(message, &buffer[1]); strcpy(message, buffer);` but nothing worked!!

Comment: crank up the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings!**

Comment: The second argument of `strcpy()` should also be a `[const] char *`, the buffer.  It is currently the second item of the buffer, a `char`.

Comment: so should it be strcpy(message, &buffer[1])?

Comment: It is more idiomatic to write "strcpy( message, buffer + 1 )"

Comment: Your segfault is being caused by something different now. Not all segfaults are created equal. I updated the answer to include a terminating null byte in your buffer (the most likely candidate for what's causing your program to crash). Paste a larger snippet if you want more help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invocation of `strcpy(3)` is incorrect. Change it to the following:

```
    buffer[199] = '\0';
    strcpy(message, &buffer[1]);
```

`strcpy(3)` has the following signature:

```
 char *
 stpcpy(char *s1, const char *s2);
```

You passed in:

```
 char *stpcpy(char *s1, const char s2); /* won't work */
```

I would suggest using `memcpy(3)` instead of `strcpy(3)` since `strcpy(3)` relies on a null character to terminate the string.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.  Is it possible that your buffer is not null-terminated?

```
char buffer[200];
buffer[0] = 'h';
buffer[1] = 'e';
buffer[2] = 'l';
buffer[3] = 'l';
buffer[4] = 'o';
buffer[5] = '\0';

// buffer was filled by recvfrom correctly, and can be printed out with printf()
char *message = (char *)malloc(200);
strcpy(message, buffer);
```

Comment: I could do printf("message is: %s", buffer); and it correctly printed out the message I sent using sendto. I am sure buffer contains the right c string